# SQL - How to select discontinuous rows from a table with one select?

Tags: mysql

```
 `SELECT * FROM Post
  WHERE Tid = Id
  ORDER BY Time
  LIMIT 0,1`

 `SELECT * FROM Post
  WHERE Tid = Id
  ORDER BY Time
  LIMIT start,offset;`
```

Can I use only one SELECT to complete this?
Just like

```
  `SELECT * FROM Post
  WHERE Tid = Id
  ORDER BY Time
  LIMIT 0,1 and start,offset;`
```

Comment: Do you mean you would like to select a number of random records from a table?

Comment: Yeah, want to select several discontinuous parts of a table.

Comment: Do you want to select the discontinuous records randomly, or according to a certain pattern?

Comment: A certain pattern? I want to select like LIMIT 2,3 AND LIMIT 6,2.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot help you until you answer my question.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. My statement is confuse. I want to select two certain part of table like `SELECT * FROM Post LIMIT 1,2; AND SELECT * FROM Post LIMIT 5,6;`

Comment: I have to search TABLE twice with two SELECT. So I want to use just one SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case combine the 2 sql statements in a union, since you cannot provide multiple limit clauses in a single select:

```
SELECT * FROM Post LIMIT 1,2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Post LIMIT 5,6;
```

However, I would add an order by clause to the 2 select statements just to make 100% sure you know which records will be selected.

UPDATE: Technically you could do this in a single statement using a running counter and filtering on the counter in where. However, that would not really be a good idea from performance wise, since mysql would have to loop through all records within the table. It cannot know which records would satisfy the criteria. Limit clauses are better optmised.

Comment: Thx a lot for your patience. But this code would just search the table once?

Comment: If you mean the union query, then no, it would search the table twice. I described an alternative approach in the update section which would scan the table only once, however, I believe that option would be slower, than the union.